Xero API Contact Phone Number
Just need a little help to solve this problem. Any and all help is appreciated
I am trying to list the contact phone number but get this error

[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2.Model.Accounting.Phone]

I am using the XeroNetStandardApp which I downloaded from Github.
The cshtml page below
@model dynamic

<h2>Xero AU Payroll Employees</h2>

<table class="table table-responsive-lg">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var employee in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
            <td>@employee.LastName</td>
            <td>@employee.JobTitle</td>
            <td>@employee.Gender</td>
            <td>@employee.Status</td>
            <td>@employee.Phone</td>
            <td>@employee.Mobile</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<hr />
<br />

Controller Code
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // Call get contacts endpoint
    var response = await Api.GetContactsAsync(XeroToken.AccessToken, TenantId);

    ViewBag.jsonResponse = response.ToJson();

    return View(response._Contacts);
}

